# How to prove that I will return home after a Schengen visa (I am a minor)

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, applications, kenyan-citizens

I am a minor and want to apply for a visa to Italy (Kenyan citizen by birth, living in Kenya). I want to visit my sister who lives in Italy. She owns a house and is a permanent resident. She divorced about a year ago. The requirements for the visa application is that you should prove that once you're given the visa you will come back to your home country. Could you give me some tips to proof that? (Also tips on how to make sure I get the visa)

Comment: Wouldn't buying an airplane ticket there and back, before you leave, be proof?

Comment: @Joren Vandamme Not necessarily - plane tickets can be easily cancelled

Comment: @JorenVandamme: Not much of a proof -- it would be easy for someone who is highly motivated to immigrate to buy a return ticket and not use the return part.

Comment: Your case is difficult (but it depends also on your nationality "residing in Kenya" means you are not from there). Ask yourself: do you have good reason to return to Kenya? Good job, or being at a good school with good forecast of good jobs. Family in Kenya (maybe with a good business you will run in future), etc. You will know better, but because your age and having a sister in Italy would no help much.

Comment: @JorenVandamme Absolutely not. Having a plane ticket doesn't prove that you'll use it.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi I am a Kenyan citizen by birth. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

I have applied a Schengen visa to Italy before when I was a student.
You can show the document to prove that you will return home after visit by asking your school/university to give you a Certificate of Study.
This letter will state "For the attention of the Italian Embassy" and contains your full name, date of birth, detail of your course including start and end date of your course and your residential address. It also have your school/university logo on it.

This is the list of documents that you should provide them when you apply for a visa.

- Appointment confirmation
- Visa application
- Copy of passport
- Copy of ID card
- 2 passport sized photos
- Introduction letter (To introduce yourself and tell them why you want to go to Italy)
- Itinerary plan
- Travel insurance
- Flight tickets confirmation (Do not pay for the ticket before you get the visa)
- Bank statement (6 months)
- Invitation letter from your sister
- Proof of relationship with the host (This could be your sister's letter and a copy of her passport)

***** If your parents or your sister pay for your trip, mention about it in the introduction letter and show them your sponsor's bank statement and a copy of his/her passport.**

The main thing is that you can show letter from your school/university that you will go to Italy on holiday and you will have to come back to finish your course.

Hope this help..
Find out more detail here : https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/italy-visa/

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Whoever did it, please explain.

Comment: Note that schengenvisainfo.com is not an official site.

Comment: And is actually infamous for providing wrong or outdated information.